# What is the correct way to insert data into database with AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'm using an AsyncTask to download the data from the server and I want to insert the data into my database. Where do I have to put the insertion code and how can I stop the AsyncTask from inserting data if the user presses the Home button?

I'm currently using `asynctask.cancel(true)` but I can't stop the database insertion.

```
public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // show progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //download data from the server
        return something;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // dismiss dialog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to do the database insertion operation in `onPostExecute()`.

If the `AsyncTask` is cancelled, then `onPostExecute()` will not be invoked.

From [The Documentation for AsyncTask.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)):

> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked
>   on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. Calling this
>   method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked. After
>   invoking this method, you should check the value returned by
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the
>   task as early as possible.

You could also add a check to `isCancelled()` in your `doInBackground()` method.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //download data from the server

        if (isCancelled()){

          //Prevent data from being inserted in the database

          try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Dismiss ProgressDialog
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    return something;
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // dismiss dialog
        //Insert data into database
    }
```

Comment: why i have to put the isCancelled() method in doInBackground if i do the insertion operation in onPostExecute()?

Comment: ok thank you i will try your suggestion and if it works i will mark your answer or i will tell you if i have a problem

Comment: if the AsyncTask iscanceled how i dismiss the progressDialog?

Comment: so if the is in the doInBackground() and downloading data from server and i cancel the AsyncTask then it will skip the if(isCancelled()) or will execute it?

Comment: @PanayiotisIrakleous even if the `AsyncTask` is cancelled, the `doInBackground()` method will run to completion.  I just updated the answer, but I haven't tested this code.  Let me know if it works~

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75655/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-panayiotis-irakleous).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you start downloading the db from server inside `doInBackground(String... params)`

Then inside `onPostExecute(String result)` method write your DB insertion logic and at the end of it close your database.

Finally finish your activity if user presses Home button (it will automatically cancel your AsyncTask)

Hope it make sense ...

Comment: if the user dont finish the activity just put it on background?

Comment: Once the user start async task it will automatically execute onPostExecute() method. So it'll finish the task. Let's not worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create new class which contains data insertion function.
Ex - 

//create new class

public class DBInsert(){

    //write data insertion login in this function.
    public string insertData(){
      ......
      ......
    }
}

//your async task.
public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // show progress dialog 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //download data from the server

        //Call db insert function.
        DBInsert.insertData();

        return something;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // dismiss dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: in this way if i press the home button and i want to cancel the AsyncTask it will crash my app in DBInsert.insertData() if it not finished

Comment: you need to handle crash   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
       super.onDestroy();
       asyncTask.cancel(true);
    }

Comment: Note that while this code may answer the question, code only answers are discouraged on SO.  See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques/148274#148274